# How to choose one data from an array without random

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native

I want to ask about how I can select one data from the array, and choose another without using a random function?

```
{
no: 1,
id_pertanyaan: "9",
pertanyaan: "Alat indra yang paling peka untuk membedakan benda panas dan benda dingin adalah?",
point: "1",
pilA: "Hidung",
pilB: "Telinga",
pilC: "Kulit",
cabang: "IPA",
jawaban: "Kulit",
keterangan: "Alat indra yang paling peka untuk membedakan benda panas dan benda dingin adalah?"
},
{
no: 2,
id_pertanyaan: "11",
pertanyaan: "Zat hijau daun disebut juga dengan?",
point: "1",
pilA: "Floem",
pilB: "Klorofil",
pilC: "Xylem",
cabang: "IPA",
jawaban: "Klorofil",
keterangan: "Zat hijau daun disebut juga dengan?"
},
```

And this is my function

```
//console.log(this.state.gagec);
    var item = this.state.pertanyaande[
      Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.pertanyaande.length)
    ];
    this.setState(
      {
        id_pertanyaan: item.id_pertanyaan,
        pertanyaan: item.pertanyaan,
        point: item.point,
        pilA: item.pilA,
        pilB: item.pilB,
        pilC: item.pilC,
        jawaban: item.jawaban,
        keterangan: item.keterangan,
      },
      () => {
        this.setTimer();
      }
    );
```

The code above is I try to be able to get the array randomly, but it raises new problems because sometimes the same data appears, I want to display data from the array only one data (not all) in a way one by one, how to get the first data in my array, then I run the script again I get the second array data?

Comment: Do you want to display each entry of the array, or may there be duplicates before all have been selected? (like 1-2-1-3)

Comment: noo, i just want to display 1 data, but i make it random, so if i run the function, there is a possibility that the same data surfaced, so I need to get just one data from the array above, and if I rerun the functions above, I get other data besides what I just got

Comment: Then you need so save the id of the prior rendered object so that you dont render it again directly afterwards

Comment: Thanks for your adviced btw, actually i've my answer, it's just to make it not random and change it to state so if id 1 is active then if the function rerun it'll get id 2 because state+1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to make it not random and change it to state so if id 1 is active then if the function rerun it'll get id 2 because state+1